# msdeploy IIS 6 to 7 migration issue

Tags: iis, iis-7, iis-6, msdeploy

I am trying to view the dependencies of my website on IIS 6.0 running on windows server 2003. When I type the following command,

```
 msdeploy -verb:getDependencies -source:metakey=lm/w3svc/1
```

I got the following error:

```
C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy>msdeploy -verb:getDependencies -source
:metakey=lm/w3svc/1
Error:  Object of type 'metaKey' and path 'lm/w3svc/1' cannot be created
Error:  The metabase key '/lm/w3svc/1' could not be found.
Error:  Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
Error count: 1
```

Can any one explain these to me?

Comment: your user is it administrator ?

Comment: Did you start your command prompt in administrator mode?

Comment: doesn't logging in as administrator take care of that?

Answer (score 7):

check if a website with Site ID 1 exists (/lm/w3svc/**1**)
Click on **Web Sites** node in left pane and check identifier column in right pan (IIS 6)

Answer (score 1):

usman has it... and no, logging in as administrator doesn't take care of running the console in administration mode. Even if you're logged in as an administrator (or THE administrator) you still have to run the console in administrator mode.